# Removing partial blur from an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a coin image which has  some blurred parts. However, i have the camera which used taking photo and i also have some representative coins from the same era. What solutions you can suggest ? I tried low pass filter but i can obtain a good result. Is there anyone suggest a solution in simple image processing tools?

Solutions may be some filter or methods or any other suggestions.

...........................
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
............................

Comment: lowpass filter is used for blurring the image, try highboost filtering (highpass + constant * image) to sharp the edges.

Comment: `deconvblind` would be my first try here. But note that almost all image processing stuff is applied to the whole image. If you have just parts of image that are blurred, you need to consider them separately.